# Android: change LayoutParams of View added by WindowManager

Tags: android, view, layoutparams

I have overlay `View` managed by `WindowManager`, just like in [this question](http://goo.gl/OD1ij).

Briefly, it looks like this:

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
my_view_layout_params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
       WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
       WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
       PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

wm.addView(my_view, my_view_layout_params);
```

It works, but if i need to change layout params, i need to remove View and add it again, like that:

```
wm.removeView(my_view);
wm.addView(my_view, my_view_layout_params);
```

It looks not very beautiful. I tried to do `my_view.setLayoutParams(my_view_layout_params)`, but it does not work unfortunately. How can i do it?

Comment: Can you not do view.getLayoutParams(), update the returned layoutparams object, and then call view.requestLayout() ?

Comment: Reuben, thanks for the reply, but unfortunately it does not work. i do 'view.getLayoutParams()', then i change 'gravity' of returned LayoutParams, do `view.requestLayout()`, and nothing changed.

Comment: WindowManager has an updateViewLayout() member... surely that's exactly what you want?

Comment: Oh. I'm surprised why did I miss it myself! Thank you. You can write the same as an answer, and I will accept it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

WindowManager has an `updateViewLayout()` member... surely that's exactly what you want?

```
windowManager.updateViewLayout(my_view, my_view_layout_params);
```

Comment: This method is helpful but be careful because some properties like the Window type cannot be changed once set, you will get an FC if you try it.

Comment: yes this worked. No need to use `setLayoutParams`. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You can use this:

```
wm.updateViewLayout(my_view,my_view_layout_params);
```