# Cant find the cause of my crash with this stack trace

Tags: android, service, view, stack-trace

What my app does, is to display a system overlay view attached through `windowManager.addView()` and `WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY` flag. This is done with a Service, which manages that view visibility and a few other things.

However, I am receiving crash reports and can't reproduce them. Also the crash stack trace has nothing to do with the package of my app, so I really can't get the root of this problem. The following are two stacktraces which come from different sources, but seem to be related:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.measure(int, int)' on a null object reference
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2388)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2101)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1297)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7011)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:777)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:590)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:763)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.View.getMeasuredWidth()' on a null object reference
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2484)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2181)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1293)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6599)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:800)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:603)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:572)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:786)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5616)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
```

It seems like the OS (ViewRootImpl) is causing this problem because it owns a null reference to my view. So I can't find a workaround for this.

It seems to happen on all Android versions since 4.4 and my app is Proguarded. These stack traces are obtained from Google Play Store crash reports

Here is how I attach view to system window as an overlay:

```
private void attachToSystemWindows(boolean overlayNavigationBar) {
    final WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);

    final DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

    final boolean isNavBarInBottom = isNavBarInBottom();

    final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            calculateWindowWidth(overlayNavigationBar, isNavBarInBottom, metrics, mNavigationBarHeight),
            calculateWindowHeight(overlayNavigationBar, isNavBarInBottom, metrics, mNavigationBarHeight),
            0,
            0,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
            0x50728,
            -3
    );
    params.gravity = Gravity.TOP;

    windowManager.addView(this, params);
}

private  boolean isNavBarInBottom() {
    final boolean isLargeDevice = getResources().getConfiguration().smallestScreenWidthDp >= 600;
    final int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;

    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
        Log.d("MeshView", "Is NavBar in bottom: " + (isLargeDevice || orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT));


    return isLargeDevice || orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
}
```

And my onMeasure method:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) Log.d("MeshView", "OnMeasure");
    setMeasuredDimension(
            Math.max(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), resolveSize(SIZE_MIN_WIDTH, widthMeasureSpec)),
            Math.max(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(), resolveSize(SIZE_MIN_HEIGHT, heightMeasureSpec))
    );
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell me that which view you are adding here : windowManager.addView(this, params);

Comment: @KishuDroid Its just a custom class extending View

Comment: @BamsBamx does my answer clarify why you got this error ?

Comment: glad I could help :)

Comment: if you need anymore info before closing the question let me know :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Amazing. I finally found the root of my problem, but not the reason... I was doing something with my view: I wanted to change its layout params depending on its orientation, so I overrode `onConfigurationChanged()`.

Then I used a nasty way to update layout params: detach and then attach it again to `WindowManager`, just like this:

```
@Override
protected void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    final ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = getLayoutParams();
    if (!(layoutParams instanceof  WindowManager.LayoutParams)) return; //Fix for some ClassCastException in Samsung devices

    final WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);

    final DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

    final boolean isNavBarInBottom = isNavBarInBottom();

    layoutParams.width = calculateWindowWidth(mOverlayNavigationBar, isNavBarInBottom, metrics, mNavigationBarHeight);
    layoutParams.height = calculateWindowHeight(mOverlayNavigationBar, isNavBarInBottom, metrics, mNavigationBarHeight);
    windowManager.removeView(this);
    windowManager.addView(this, layoutParams);
}
```

I guess something bad happens in the `ViewRootImpl` class, causing it to not handle the reattach properly, causing an error.

To fix this, just must go through the proper way: Use the `WindowManager.updateViewLayout();` method:

```
@Override
protected void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) Log.d("MeshView", "OnConfigurationChanged");

    final ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = getLayoutParams();
    if (!(layoutParams instanceof  WindowManager.LayoutParams)) return; //Fix for some ClassCastException in Samsung devices

    final WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);

    final DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

    final boolean isNavBarInBottom = isNavBarInBottom();

    layoutParams.width = calculateWindowWidth(mOverlayNavigationBar, isNavBarInBottom, metrics, mNavigationBarHeight);
    layoutParams.height = calculateWindowHeight(mOverlayNavigationBar, isNavBarInBottom, metrics, mNavigationBarHeight);
    //windowManager.removeView(this);    DON'T DO THIS
    //windowManager.addView(this, layoutParams);    DON'T DO THIS

    windowManager.updateViewLayout(this, layoutParams); //DO THIS INSTEAD
}
```

This seems to fix my problem. I must thank to the author of this post, which allowed me to find this fix): [Android: change LayoutParams of View added by WindowManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9358288/android-change-layoutparams-of-view-added-by-windowmanager)

Answer (score 4):

I think you are not passing the correct flag while creating `params`.

```
final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
        calculateWindowWidth(overlayNavigationBar, isNavBarInBottom, metrics, mNavigationBarHeight),
        calculateWindowHeight(overlayNavigationBar, isNavBarInBottom, metrics, mNavigationBarHeight),
        0,
        0,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
        0x50728, // problem might be here.
        -3
);
```

It should be one of [these values](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#flags).

So use it something like this (avoid passing hex values directly):

```
final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
        calculateWindowWidth(overlayNavigationBar, isNavBarInBottom, metrics, mNavigationBarHeight),
        calculateWindowHeight(overlayNavigationBar, isNavBarInBottom, metrics, mNavigationBarHeight),
        0,
        0,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALLOW_LOCK_WHILE_SCREEN_ON, //any flag
        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
);
```

I have also [referenced PixelFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PixelFormat.html#TRANSLUCENT).

Try to change like this and see if that works.

Comment: Ok, your answer may be right. I will try that and once I check if it works I will post the result, thanks. I am opened to new answers though ;)

Comment: @BamsBamx, ok sure :)

Comment: I finally found the problem (I will post as an answer in this question), but your answer had nothing to do with my problem, because the problem root was another one. Thank you anyway

Comment: @BamsBamx, Congrats. I tried to find the problem depending on the information you provided. :P

Answer (score 4):

is short when you remove the view by(`windowManager.removeView(this)`) after a chain of calls ViewRoot.dispatchDetachedFromWindow() which essentially sets the viewroot's view to null which is why you have the NPE while in traversal.

In Details:
by doing

> `windowManager.removeView(this);`

you essentially call die on the ViewRoot of the view, which then sends `MSG_DIE` to its handler so it kills is later when safe and adds the view to `mDyingViews` list in the WindowManagerGlobal. this is all fine,

however by calling:

> `windowManager.addView(this, layoutParams);`

you force the death of the ViewRoot and call `doDie()` and consecutively `ViewRoot.dispatchDetachedFromWindow()` which sets the view to null while in traversal and you have NPE.

for more info check [WindowManagerGlobal](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/view/WindowManagerGlobal.java) and [ViewRootImpl](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/view/ViewRootImpl.java)

Answer (score 0):

Proguard can cause Stack Trace issue, though there should have been a hint of your own code, even though further reading of that needs deciphering, so this stumps me, turn Proguard off via Gradle, then run again and see.

Comment: Yes, you are right. However, its not the case, because I have already test it and there is no way I can reproduce it

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in my app I solved the problem using

```
public static final int TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT;
```

instead of TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY. I guess the view is already destroyed before onMeasure() is called. This type of overlay somehow creates a problem on especially no named pre kit kat devices.

Note: If you want your overlay window to be displayed behind status bar and still above all other applications use;

```
public static final int TYPE_PHONE;
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it does not apply to my app, because it must overlay the system but let the windows behind handle all touches. ´TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT´ wont let that

Comment: No it will allow that just use the right parameters.
LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL | LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
are the ones you need.
Refer to the documentation:
    /** Window flag: even when this window is focusable (its
         * {@link #FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE} is not set), allow any pointer events
         * outside of the window to be sent to the windows behind it.  Otherwise
         * it will consume all pointer events itself, regardless of whether they
         * are inside of the window. */

    public static final int FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL    = 0x00000020;